# Run new spider or get new list of urls for scraping

Tags: python, scrapy

I've just written a simple spider using Scrapy. And now I'm wondering if there is a way to crawl links by chunks and restart the spider when the previous spider has done his job?
I mean, in `__init__` of spider I get 100 starting URLs from a database and when all of those links are crawled and the spider terminated, I want to start a new spider automatically. How can I do this? Or may be there is a way to get a new chunk of URLs without restarting the spider?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a method to the `spider_idle` signal so that when the spider idles (i.e. it is done processing all requests and items), it will execute that method, or in your case, get more URLs to crawl.

Here is an example:

```
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy import Spider, signals
from scrapy.http import Request


class MySpider(Spider):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = self.fetch_more_urls()
        dispatcher.connect(self.do_when_idle, signals.spider_idle)

    def do_when_idle(self, spider):

        if spider != self:
            return

        urls = self.fetch_more_urls()

        for url in urls:
            req = Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
            self.crawler.engine.crawl(req, spider)

    def parse(self, response):
        # parse function
```

The spider will run the `do_when_idle` function after it has processed/scraped your initial fetched requests under `__init__`.

For more info about signals, see: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html